# C#. SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync does not throw OperationCanceledException when the task is canceled

Tags: c#, async-await, task

First of all, excuse my English. I will be brief, in the attached code after Task.WhenAny what I expected was that at least three of the five tasks would be canceled, but all ended satisfactorily. SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync does not throw OperationCanceledException when the tasks are canceled.

```
class Program
{
    private static CancellationTokenSource methodRequests = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] delays = new int[] { 5000, 5010, 5020, 5030, 5040 };

        IEnumerable<Task> tasks = from delay in delays select MethodAsync(delay, new CancellationTokenSource().Token);

        Task.WhenAny(tasks).Wait();

        methodRequests.Cancel();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task MethodAsync(int milliseconds, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var methodRequest = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, methodRequests.Token);

        try
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync(methodRequest.Token);

            Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);

            Console.WriteLine($"Task finished {milliseconds}");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Task canceled {milliseconds}");
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: When you created `tasks`, you created a new `CanvellationTokenSource` for each task. You should be passing  `methodRequests.Token` where you're currently passing `new CancellationTokenSource().Token`.

Comment: @Simon: there is nothing wrong logically with the handling of tokens here. The OP has a master token in `methodRequests`, and links all of the other tokens to that. So while each call has a unique token, each of those is linked to the master and will be cancelled when the master is. In this example, it's not _necessary_ to have all those tokens, but it's not _wrong_ either.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I didn't notice the linking step. Not to be argumentative, but `new CancellationTokenSource().Token` can never be useful, so that can definitely be seen as an error of logic, as one would only ever pass a cancellation token with the expectation that cancellation can be performed!

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie: I agree it's not useful, but that doesn't mean it won't work or that it's in any way related to the _problem_ that the OP is asking about (cancellation _can_ be performed, as the token value created winds up being used as a sort of placeholder for the linked token source...again, I agree not _useful_, but not strictly speaking _incorrect_ per se either...in this context, giving the benefit of the doubt, I view this degenerate cancel token as some vestigial hold-over from whatever the original, real-world code looked like).

Comment: Thanks for answer so soon. It's like @PeterDuniho says, in my application I need a master token. With the five tasks I pretended to emulate MethodAsync calls from different threads. What happens is that my class uses IDisposable and although Dispose should not be called until the instance is no longer used, I want my class to cancel all input / output operations by the master token in case the client code commit that "infraction" and do not cancel the pending tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the `MethodAsync()` method is never returning until the `Thread.Sleep()` method completes. This means that each task doesn't even *start* until the previous one finishes. Here is a version of your code that illustrates this more clearly:

```
private static CancellationTokenSource methodRequests = new CancellationTokenSource();
private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] delays = new int[] { 5000, 5010, 5020, 5030, 5040 };

    IEnumerable<Task> tasks = from delay in delays select MethodAsync(delay, new CancellationTokenSource().Token);

    Task.WhenAny(tasks).Wait();

    methodRequests.Cancel();

    ReadKey();
}

static async Task MethodAsync(int milliseconds, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var methodRequest = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, methodRequests.Token);

    try
    {
        WriteLine($"waiting semaphore (will wait {milliseconds} ms)");
        await semaphore.WaitAsync(methodRequest.Token);

        WriteLine($"waiting {milliseconds} ms");
        Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);

        WriteLine($"Task finished {milliseconds}");
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        WriteLine($"Task canceled {milliseconds}");
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

The output for that is:

```
waiting semaphore (will wait 5000 ms)
waiting 5000 ms
Task finished 5000
waiting semaphore (will wait 5010 ms)
waiting 5010 ms
Task finished 5010
waiting semaphore (will wait 5020 ms)
waiting 5020 ms
Task finished 5020
waiting semaphore (will wait 5030 ms)
waiting 5030 ms
Task finished 5030
waiting semaphore (will wait 5040 ms)
waiting 5040 ms
Task finished 5040
```

As you can see, you never even see the *"waiting for semaphore..."* message until the previous task completes. This is because your LINQ `select` cannot proceed to the next element in the sequence until the `MethodAsync()` method returns the value for the current element, and that doesn't happen until the `Thread.Sleep()` completes.

You may have thought that the `await semaphore.WaitAsync()` should yield to the caller, allowing the `Task` to be returned and the enumeration of the `select` to continue. But, this would happen only if the semaphore was unavailable. It's available on each call, because each call happens only after the previous call completes, because when that previous call was made, the semaphore was available. Since the semaphore is available when the call to `WaitAsync()` is made, the `await` completes synchronously. I.e. the code proceeds directly to the `Thread.Sleep()` rather than yielding to the caller.

The net effect is that the call to `WhenAny()` doesn't even happen until *all* of the `Thread.Sleep()` calls (and of course, all of the `semaphore.WaitAsync()` calls as well) have completed.

Presumably this came up in some real-world scenario, and the code you posted is just for demonstration purposes. So, it's difficult to say exactly what you should fix. But, in the code example you posted, it's sufficient to just switch to `Task.Delay()` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`. Since the delay is always non-zero, the method will always yield at that point, even if the semaphore itself was available. This allows the `select` to proceed to the next call to `MethodAsync()` before the "work" in the current call has completed.

In this way, all of the tasks are in fact created concurrently as you'd originally expected.

Whatever the real-world code looks like, what you want to do is make sure that you've got an asynchronous operation after the semaphore acquisition, to allow the method to actually return to the caller, so that the next operation(s) can be started as well.

Comment: Great answer! Small question, not that it would necessarily be useful in a real world scenario, but would adding a `Task.Yield` right before awaiting the semaphore fix the issue as well, without changing the rest of the code? (Of course though, mixing async code with blocking calls such as `.Wait` or `Thread.Sleep` is always a bad idea anyways)

Comment: @Sergio0694: introducing an `await Task.Yield()` at any point before the call to `Thread.Sleep()` would force control to be returned to the caller, so yes...in some sense that would "fix" the issue. As you note, it wouldn't really fix the code in the most useful way though.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you. This is the solution. Actually in the original test code I had Task.Delay and it worked as expected; but I did not deduce that it was for what you explain even though the debugger and the evidence pointed to it. With this test I just wanted to check the master token, the rest will not be in my implementation of the real world.